# Accessing json whose name is in variable

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON document

```
var config  = {name:"Sentiment", type:"pie"};
```

and I have a variable

```
var a="config";
```

Now I want to access "name" of the JSON using

```
a.name
```

How to do it?

I know that I can access it by `config.name` but my dynamic file is returning a variable having "config" stored as string, so how can I access it by that?

Comment: If the variables are in the same scope you could do:
    `this[a].name`

Comment: After reading some of those (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+"variable+variables"), I think @drowsy solution is better

Answer (score 0):

Never, never ever use eval!

Can you have this structure?

```
var data = {
config: {name:"Sentiment", type:"pie"}
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
var a = "config";
console.log(data[a].name); //logs Sentiment
```